# Parse html content from an input string using javascript/lodash

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, lodash

I have a string like this:

```
var inputString = "some sample string with <span data-id='24' data-name='cat'">cat</span> and <span data-id='25' data-name='dog'">dog</span>"
```

What I'm trying to do is to extract the data from the spans into a json array:

```
var json = [
    {
        id: '24',
        name: 'cat'
    },
    {
        id:'25',
        name: 'dog'
    }
];
```

and then also strip off the spans from the string:

```
var outputString = "some sample string with cat and dog";
```

Any idea on how I can do this using plain javascript or lodash? Is there a function that will extract all the span segments for me, or do I need to do it step by step, finding the indexes of the span elements starting from the first one? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assign the string to the `innerHTML` of a document fragment, then use DOM functions to extract the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd parse the string as HTML, extract the data attributes, and use `textContent` to get the text

```js
var inputString = "some sample string with <span data-id='24' data-name='cat'>cat</span> and <span data-id='25' data-name='dog'>dog</span>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc    = parser.parseFromString(inputString, "text/html");
var json   = [].slice.call(doc.querySelectorAll('span')).map(function(span) {
    return {id : span.dataset.id, name : span.dataset.name};
});

var outputString = doc.body.textContent;

console.log(json);
console.log('------');
console.log(outputString);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: This is great! Do you know if there is an easy way to find the start and end indices of the word (ex. dog or cat)? Where dog appears and where cat appears in the string (ignoring the spans).

Comment: Sure, when you have the string you can use `indexOf` to get the index of a word in a string

Comment: Hmm ok...I'm just wondering how I could get indexes only for the words in the spans though...what if there is another dog elsewhere in the string...

Comment: Well, `indexOf` gets the index for the *first* one only, but you can set a starting point as well, so you could find any number of matches if you start by finding one, and then say the starting index of "cat" was 20, you could do `str.indexOf("cat", 21)` to start looking from character 21 in the string etc. to find the index of the second one and so on.

Comment: Ah ok got it! One last question---what if the second cat is the one that's in the span? Is there a way for me to know whether to look for the first cat or the second?

Comment: You could use `querySelector` to get the span, then get the text from the span only, not the entire string, and search inside that.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is great and definitely answers the question, but I wanted to provide an alternative answer utilizing regexp.  I am not the best with regex, but this is what I came up with...

```
const input = "some sample string with <span data-id='24' data-name='cat'>cat</span> and <span data-id='25' data-name='dog'>dog</span>";

const dataReg = new RegExp(/data-(\w+)=[\'|\"](\w+)[\'|\"] data-(\w+)=[\'|\"](\w+)[\'+\"]/g);

const json = [];

// get the matches and add them to the json array
while ((g = dataReg.exec(input)) !== null) {
  // we only care about matches after idx 1
  let m = {};
  m[g[1]] = g[2];
  m[g[3]] = g[4];
  json.push(m);
}

console.log(json); // [{id: "24", name: "cat"}, {id: "25", name: "dog"}]

// strip the html
let safeStr = input.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');

console.log(safeStr);  // some sample string with cat and dog"
```

You can preview it here: https://jsbin.com/quyufoc/edit?js,console

Comment: This is great too. With this method if I wanted to also find the start and end index of each word (dog and cat) in the output string, how could I do that?

Comment: I know I could use the indexOf function, but in case there other dogs and cats in the sentence not wrapped in the span, it may throw me off.

Comment: Do you want the index of them in the safeStr?  and your second comment definitely nails a potential problem... I suppose that you are wanting the index of the dog and cat that appear in the <span> tag but including the offset of the characters removed before it appears?

Comment: Yes, I just need the indexes of dog and cat in safeStr. So the offset should not include the span tag stuff.